# Failing to write in hdf5 file

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to create hdf5 file, but the output file is empty.

I have written a python code which is supposed to run in loop and write string in the created datasets.
After the file gets saved, I found that the output file is always empty.

Below is the piece of code I have written:

```
h5_file_name = 'sample.h5'
hf = h5py.File(h5_file_name, 'w')
g1 = hf.create_group('Objects')
dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
d1 = g1.create_dataset('D1', (2, 10), dtype=dt)
d2 = g1.create_dataset('D2', (3, 10), dtype=dt)
for i in range(10):
    d1[0][i] = 'Sample'
    d1[1][i] = str(i)
    d2[0][i] = 'Hello'
    d2[1][i] = 'World'
    d2[2][i] = str(i)
hf.close()
```

The output file is empty as mentioned above.

Can anyone please point out what am I missing here, many thanks in advance !

Comment: Double check h5py docs. You have 2 special type variables on each row, and I think you are limited to 1 per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me (in an ipython session):

```
In [1]: import h5py                                                                                    
In [2]: h5_file_name = 'sample.h5' 
   ...: hf = h5py.File(h5_file_name, 'w') 
   ...: g1 = hf.create_group('Objects') 
   ...: dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str) 
   ...: d1 = g1.create_dataset('D1', (2, 10), dtype=dt) 
   ...: d2 = g1.create_dataset('D2', (3, 10), dtype=dt) 
   ...: for i in range(10): 
   ...:     d1[0][i] = 'Sample' 
   ...:     d1[1][i] = str(i) 
   ...:     d2[0][i] = 'Hello' 
   ...:     d2[1][i] = 'World' 
   ...:     d2[2][i] = str(i) 
   ...: hf.close()
```

This runs, and creates a file.  It is not "empty" in the normal sense.  But if by file being empty you mean that it didn't write the words to the file?  All that's present is the original `''`.

```
In [4]: hf = h5py.File(h5_file_name, 'r')                                                              
In [5]: hf['Objects/D1']                                                                               
Out[5]: <HDF5 dataset "D1": shape (2, 10), type "|O">
In [6]: hf['Objects/D1'][:]                                                                            
Out[6]: 
array([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], dtype=object)
```

===

The problem isn't with the file setup, but rather with how you are trying to set elements:

```
In [45]: h5_file_name = 'sample.h5' 
    ...: hf = h5py.File(h5_file_name, 'w') 
    ...: g1 = hf.create_group('Objects') 
    ...: dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str) 
    ...: d1 = g1.create_dataset('D1', (2, 10), dtype=dt) 
    ...: d2 = g1.create_dataset('D2', (3, 10), dtype=dt) 
    ...:                                                                                               
In [46]: d1[:]                                                                                         
Out[46]: 
array([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], dtype=object)
In [47]: d1[0][0] = 'sample'                                                                           
In [48]: d1[:]                                                                                         
Out[48]: 
array([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], dtype=object)
```

Use the `tuple` style of indexing:

```
In [49]: d1[0, 0] = 'sample'                                                                           
In [50]: d1[:]                                                                                         
Out[50]: 
array([['sample', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], dtype=object)
```

With a numpy array `d1[0][0]=...` works, but that's because `d1[0]` is a `view` of `d1`, but `h5py` (apparently) does not quite replicate this.  `d1[0]` is a copy, an actual numpy array, not the dataset itself.

Variations on that whole-array indexing:

```
In [51]: d1[0, :] = 'sample'                                                                           
In [52]: d1[1, :] = np.arange(10)                                                                      
In [53]: d1[:]                                                                                         
Out[53]: 
array([['sample', 'sample', 'sample', 'sample', 'sample', 'sample',
        'sample', 'sample', 'sample', 'sample'],
       ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']], dtype=object)
In [54]: d2[:,0] = ['one','two','three']                                                               
In [55]: d2[:]                                                                                         
Out[55]: 
array([['one', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['two', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['three', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], dtype=object)
```

Verifying the change in type with indexing:

```
In [64]: type(d1)                                                                                      
Out[64]: h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset
In [65]: type(d1[0])                                                                                   
Out[65]: numpy.ndarray
```

`d1[0][0]='foobar'` would change that `d1[0]` array without affecting the `d1` dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this can be solved using h5py but if you are not bound to a specific library, take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it is really easy to handle HDF5 files with it.

Using HDFql in Python, your use-case can be solved with the help of hyperslabs as follows:

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("CREATE AND USE FILE sample.h5")

HDFql.execute("CREATE CHUNKED(1) DATASET objects/D1 AS VARCHAR(10, 2)")

HDFql.execute("CREATE CHUNKED(1) DATASET objects/D2 AS VARCHAR(10, 3)")

for i in range(10):

    HDFql.execute("INSERT INTO objects/D1[%d:::1] VALUES(Sample, %d)" % (i, i))

    HDFql.execute("INSERT INTO objects/D2[%d:::1] VALUES(Hello, World, %d)" % (i, i))

HDFql.execute("CLOSE FILE")
```

Additional examples on how to use HDFql can be found [here](http://www.hdfql.com/examples).